# How to click on the particular value of slider through program

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Slider - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#slider").slider();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="slider"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

In the above code, i have to click on the slider(slider value have to be 60) automatically through program . how can i do that

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Do you instead mean that you want to programmatically set the value of `60` on the slider?

Comment: `$( "#slider" ).slider( "value", 60);` http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-value